# lost title UIButton when tableView scrolling

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a UITableView with several custom cells. The problem I have now is that the which I have to display title button when button is selected but  The pointButton can also change its own state. The style changes depending on the state. Here is the code in the points button :

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FrendsTableViewCellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! FriendEventialTableViewCell 
        let f = self.user![indexPath.row]

        cell.userName.text = "\(f.firstname!) \(f.lastname!)"
        cell.titleName.text = f.jobTitle ?? ""

        if f.avatar != nil{
            cell.imageUser.af_setImage(withURL: URL(string: f.avatar!)!)
        }

        cell.selectButton.setTitle("Select", for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.selectButton.setTitleColor(ColorConstant.charcoalGrey, for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.selectButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.selectButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 151.0/255.0, green: 151.0/255.0, blue: 151.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor

        cell.selectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EventialFrendsViewController.followButtonClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.selectButton.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell

   }
```

button Action, which detects when a button is pressed

```
  @objc func followButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)

        if sender.isSelected
        {
            sender.setTitle("Select", for: UIControlState.normal)
            sender.setTitleColor(ColorConstant.charcoalGrey, for: UIControlState.normal)
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 151.0/255.0, green: 151.0/255.0, blue: 151.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            sender.isSelected = false
            print("select")

        }
        else
        {
            sender.setTitle("Selected", for: UIControlState.normal)
            sender.setTitleColor(ColorConstant.charcoalGrey, for: UIControlState.normal)
            sender.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 215.0/255.0, green: 190.0/255.0, blue: 10.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
            sender.backgroundColor = ColorConstant.sunYellow
            sender.isSelected = true
            print("selected")
        }

    }
```

Comment: You have to keep the `selected` state in the data model (`user`) and set the title accordingly in `cellForRow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain an array of selected indexes.

```
var selectedIndexes: [IndexPath : Bool] = [:]
```

Do UI customisation for selected and unselected buttons in `cellForRowAt` method.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FrendsTableViewCellId", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! FriendEventialTableViewCell

    // Set up cell here

    if selectedIndexes[indexPath] ?? false {
        // customise cell for selected state
    } else {
        // customise cell for default state
    }
    return cell
}
```

Toggle the state on button callback and reload that cell.

```
@objc func followButtonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
    let buttonPosition = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableView)
    if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition) {
        selectedIndexes[indexPath] = !(selectedIndexes[indexPath] ?? false)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: A separate index array is a very bad idea if the data model is a custom struct or class  anyway. It's much more efficient to add an appropriate property to the model.

Comment: hi bilal i have error " Cannot subscript a value of type '[IndexPath : Bool]' with an index of type 'Int' "

Comment: @Bilal the error at selectedIndexes[indexPath!] = !(selectedIndexes[indexPath?.row] ?? false)

Comment: Remove the ‘.row’. Using mobile app so couldn’t compile it.

Comment: As @vadian suggested it would be better to create a property in data model to get the following status instead of maintaining index array.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Whenever you update the title.

Comment: Definitely this does not work if the changed state is not saved somewhere and considered in `cellForRow`